# Database design to track multi-step process

Tags: database, workflow, database-schema

I am working on a database to handle the process flow of a multi-step process.

Each specific process includes several actions.

Each action within a specific process uses some common files and some unique files.  The actual actions will be performed by a person with specific skills.  For instance, the first action may be to take one (of the common to each process) files and create a new file.  The second action will be to take the common file and the new file and create a third file; etc.

The problem is that each action is just unique enough that I think I need separate tables for each type of action.

So my issue is how to “track” them within the process.

Imagine a car wash facility as the overall idea.
    Each car would be the same as a specific project
    Each car may have a different process assigned to it.
        One process is to run it through the tunnel and hand dry; a two step flow.
        Another is to run it through the tunnel, hand dry and vacuum; a three step flow.
        A third is to run it through the tunnel, hand dry and detail; a different three step flow.
Now imagine that the car could be teleported between steps.  (I know; if I could teleport the car, I certainly wouldn’t be asking this question on stackoverflow.)
Also that the cars could sit in a big parking lot between actions.
And finally, that workers that were equipped and allowed to do a specific action; could check to see or be informed if there were any cars awaiting (their) action and could teleport them from the parking lot (checking them out), do their work and teleport them back to the parking lot (checking them back in.)

(I left out some stuff that would be obvious; such as checking in or out - updates the car’s project status; including checking in and out time constraints; there is an inherent order (cannot dry before washing); some actions could occur in parallel (such as vacuuming while the car is in the tunnel), etc.  This car wash analogy isn’t perfect, but seems to be pretty good.)

What I am trying to figure out is how best to set up the database to handle this.

And while realizing that the initial idea is that it is only for three specific processes and only car washes, I NEED to generalize this to handle more than just these three different processes and more or less than just two or three steps and to handle the addition of (say) oil changes which require completely different inputs but would still be just steps in a process.

I am sure this has been done to death before, so simply pointing me to an example is great.  (I read the question and answer to an example of "BoxItems" flow, but that was missing the basics.)

Where I am hung up at is my mindset of a process needing to handle varying individual ordered steps.
    One process needing action one, then two, then three
    and another needing action one, then four and five in parallel, then action two.

Obviously, I cannot have a process table that has varying number of fields for differing records.  Each of these varying fields being a foreign key to a table containing unique actions.  (And besides; the process table would be more high-level information such as owner, percent completed, etc.)

I have gone down the path of a table (flow for lack of a better name) that defines each process flow; one specific sequence of actions per record.  But that seems to just be moving the conundrum from the process table to flow table.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

thank you,
chuck

Comment: I might have gotten lost in your explanation, but perhaps something akin to the Party/Party-Relationship pattern would be helpful? (http://www.tdan.com/view-articles/5014/)

Comment: Check out the Activities chapter in Hay's Enterprise Modeling Patterns. He discusses activities with dependencies. Cheap on Safari

Comment: For what it is worth, I decided to go down the path of creating a linked list type of process.  I am creating separate tables for each of the different task types (aka, tunnel wash, vacuum, detail, etc).  Each record will have two fields indicating the previous task and two fields indicating the next task.  The two fields will hold the task type (the table) and the other will hold the specific record in that table).  This will allow unknown future tasks, etc.  At this point it does not allow parallel tasks.

Comment: For thebjorn; I read the article you listed and while it did not help me in this situation, I have assimilated some of those ideas into other ideas.  I liked the idea of abstracting or making more generic some of the "everybody knows what a person structure looks like" concepts.  I appreciate the link.

Comment: For Neil, I didn't get a chance to get the book, but I will certainly be on the look out for it.  I read about both the book and the author and I think you pointed me to a great reference.  Thank you.

Comment: I do not think I can mark my question as closed or answered or even just OBE.  Maybe someone with higher rep or whatever can close this.  Thank you, chuck